# document.submit() not working in IE (works in chrome,ff,and safari)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have searched thoroughly, and cannot find a solution that fits my specific situation.  I have a popup window built using `window.open("","","")`, and inside that window I build a form which looks like:

```
<form id="uploadImageForm" action="<?php  echo $_GET['action']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="files[0]" size="40"/>
    <input type="text" name="token" value="<?php  echo $_GET['token']; ?>"/>
</form>
```

I then call a function called `doUpload` from another window.  I can get into this function just fine, and the `document.forms["uploadImageForm"].` stuff works really well in all other browsers but IE.  Watching variables in the DOM using IE's debugger has shown that `document.forms["uploadImageForm"].action ="http://server_api_call.html";`and
    `document.forms["uploadImageForm"].token.value = comGroupId;` 
both work as they should, but for whatever reason, it dies on `document.forms["uploadImageForm"].submit();`

This form is located at www.joynme.com/alex/w/index.html -> "Log In" -> "Sign un with Email"
Any help is much appreciated! (Also first post, so sorry if my formatting sucks!)

Comment: And error messages? Is there anything else to your form?

Comment: That is the entirety of the form, I'm getting no error messages, and the console is clean

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add the name to the form? `<form name="uploadImageForm" id="uploadImageForm" ...`

Comment: Try: `document.getElementById("uploadImageForm").submit();` instead

Comment: I have tried this alternative before, and still nothing...I've added a name to the form, as well as the `getElementBtId` DOM wording, and nothing yet

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps IE has an issue with the form because it does not have `<input type="submit" />`.

In either case, your method for referencing form elements is outdated and non-standard. you should refer to HTML nodes by standardized methods: `document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByTagName`, etc. You can also use the more dated `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` methods (IE8+).

Comment: the javascript now reads: `document.getElementById("uploadImageForm").action ="API_CALL";
 document.getElementById("uploadImageForm").token.value =comGroupId;
 document.getElementById("uploadImageForm").submit();`

Comment: and the form now has the `<input type="submit" />` tag associated with it, and nothing has changed yet :/

Comment: Is the form available (script located after the form elements, triggers after the DOM or window events triggers)?

Comment: I have the function call inside a separate window, which is built by the action `imageUploadWindow = window.open()`, and then called by `imageUploadWindow.doUpload(arg1,arg2)`, and the form is built long before this function call is triggered...I believe this was your question? Not 100% sure what you were asking

Comment: An example (http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net) could help us help you (there are too many speculations about your code).

Comment: if you go to www.joynme.com/alex/w/index.html click on the login button on the left menu, and click sign up with email, you will be able to go through the flow

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this property before submitting:

`document.forms["uploadImageForm"].setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");`

IE has issues with submitting multipart forms through js

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

I was passing in an `action=" "` string as a blank string initially when building the form.  However, I was then performing a `document.myformname.action="API_CALL.html"`, which was adding the action twice to the form...apparently IE does not like this

Cheers! and thanks for the suggestions,
Alex